# MVC WebAPI 2 with AngularjS Err_Connection_Refused

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am new to WebAPI, AngularJS, and .NET Authentication and I am using this tutorial **[HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/742532/Using-Web-API-Individual-User-Account-plus-CORS-En)** (~under 10 mins long), and I am getting an error in regards to `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, normally I can just Google away at this but I am getting really lost since these are all new technologies to me.

Everything worked smooth until I tried to "register" near the end of the tutorial, this is where the error appears. Can someone double check that tutorial and see if they can get register to work, or quick tell if something they use is out of date or broken? As mentioned it takes literally under 10 minutes to do.

Here is my code regardless

**AngularJSClient Solution**

[image]

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Module name is handy for logging
    var id = 'app';
    // Create the module and define its dependencies.
    var app = angular.module('app', [
    ]);
    app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        // Use x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Type
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
        // Override $http service's default transformRequest
        $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function (data) {
            /**
             * The workhorse; converts an object to x-www-form-urlencoded serialization.
             * @param {Object} obj
             * @return {String}
             */
            var param = function (obj) {
                var query = '';
                var name, value, fullSubName, subName, subValue, innerObj, i;
                for (name in obj) {
                    value = obj[name];
                    if (value instanceof Array) {
                        for (i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
                            subValue = value[i];
                            fullSubName = name + '[' + i + ']';
                            innerObj = {};
                            innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
                            query += param(innerObj) + '&';
                        }
                    }
                    else if (value instanceof Object) {
                        for (subName in value) {
                            subValue = value[subName];
                            fullSubName = name + '[' + subName + ']';
                            innerObj = {};
                            innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
                            query += param(innerObj) + '&';
                        }
                    }
                    else if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
                        query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&';
                    }
                }
                return query.length ? query.substr(0, query.length - 1) : query;
            };
            return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' ? param(data) : data;
        }];
    }]);
    // Execute bootstrapping code and any dependencies.
    app.run(['$q', '$rootScope',
        function ($q, $rootScope) {
        }]);
})();
```

**mainCtrl.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var controllerId = 'mainCtrl';
    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
        ['userAccountService', mainCtrl]);
    function mainCtrl(userAccountService) {
        // Using 'Controller As' syntax, so we assign this to the vm variable (for viewmodel).
        var vm = this;
        // Bindable properties and functions are placed on vm.
        vm.title = 'mainCtrl';
        vm.isRegistered = false;
        vm.isLoggedIn = false;
        vm.userData = {
            userName: "",
            password: "",
            confirmPassword: "",
        };
        vm.registerUser = registerUser;
        vm.loginUser = loginUser;
        vm.getValues = getValues;
        function registerUser() {
            userAccountService.registerUser(vm.userData).then(function (data) {
                vm.isRegistered = true;
            }, function (error, status) {
                vm.isRegistered = false;
                console.log(status);
            });
        }
        function loginUser() {
            userAccountService.loginUser(vm.userData).then(function (data) {
                vm.isLoggedIn = true;
                vm.userName = data.userName;
                vm.bearerToken = data.access_token;
            }, function (error, status) {
                vm.isLoggedIn = false;
                console.log(status);
            });
        }
        function getValues() {
            userAccountService.getValues().then(function (data) {
                vm.values = data;
                console.log('back... with success');
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

**userAccountService.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var serviceId = 'userAccountService';
    angular.module('app').factory(serviceId, ['$http', '$q', userAccountService]);
    function userAccountService($http, $q) {
        // Define the functions and properties to reveal.
        var service = {
            registerUser: registerUser,
            loginUser: loginUser,
            getValues: getValues,
        };
        var serverBaseUrl = "http://localhost:60737";

        return service;
        var accessToken = "";
        function registerUser(userData) {
            var accountUrl = serverBaseUrl + "/api/Account/Register";
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: accountUrl,
                data: userData,
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, cfg) {
                console.log(data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (err, status) {
                console.log(err);
                deferred.reject(status);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        function loginUser(userData) {
            var tokenUrl = serverBaseUrl + "/Token";
            if (!userData.grant_type) {
                userData.grant_type = "password";
            }
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: tokenUrl,
                data: userData,
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, cfg) {
                // save the access_token as this is required for each API call. 
                accessToken = data.access_token;
                // check the log screen to know currently back from the server when a user log in successfully.
                console.log(data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (err, status) {
                console.log(err);
                deferred.reject(status);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        function getValues() {
            var url = serverBaseUrl + "/api/values/";
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                headers: getHeaders(),
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, cfg) {
                console.log(data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (err, status) {
                console.log(err);
                deferred.reject(status);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        // we have to include the Bearer token with each call to the Web API controllers. 
        function getHeaders() {
            if (accessToken) {
                return { "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken };
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

**WebAPI2 Solution**

[image]

**WebApiConfig.cs***

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

```
    //Enable CORS for all origins, all headers, and all methods,
    // You can customize this to match your requirements
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

}

Again the error I am getting is while testing the Register function for the first time in the tutorial. I get `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: you see that error where?

Comment: @RobertLevy I actually reviewed the code again found the problem, but this also leads me to a question. In userAccountServices, there is a `var serverBaseurl = "http:localhostxxxx"`, I guessed on this and changed it to the one that localhost port that loaded the webapi and it worked. When I Deploy this online, will that have to be my example.com url? And do these two items get deployed at the same location? new to using two different projects together.

Comment: @Austin and the problem was?

Comment: @osiris355 I actually could never figure it out. I think I found a completed tutorial somewhere and just used that as a reference to learn. I got the concepts from the tutorial, so I just must have "mis-did" something. Sorry that I didn't find any answer :(

Comment: I found that I was making a pretty stupid mistake with the actual ripple emulator. There is a drop down for disabling cross domain proxy and that seemed to solve my issue with the emaulator. Unfortunately I still cannot get it working with a real device. I am still getting connection refused even after trying some android network permissions

Answer (score 3):

1. Use this package "*Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors*"
2. Add **config.EnableCors()** to *WebApiConfig* like

   ```
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
   {
       //Cors code
       config.EnableCors();

       config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
   }
   ```
3. Add it finaly in *ConfigureAuth* *OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions*
   **AllowInsecureHttp = true**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  It's all about CORS.  I'm having a "Failed to load resource" error now but mine should be for a different reason because my cors code has been working for months.

I hope this helps...

https://github.com/MashupJS/MashupJS/blob/master/docs/mashupApi/WebApi-Cors-Chrome.md

Here is how to create a WebApi that supports CORS from scratch.  The Microsoft documents didn't get me there so once I figured it out I wrote my own.

Good luck!